# Nested subqueries in SQL from hr.employees

Tags: sql, subquery

There is a task: using the HR.EMPLOYEES table, get a list of departments in which the average work experience is above the average for the entire company.

I tried to implement it this way. I know that the request is not correct, but I don’t understand how to distribute it to the entire company

```
select department_id
from hr.employees
where avg(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, hire_date)) > (select hire_date from hr.employees where avg(MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, hire_date))
```

The database looks like this:

```
EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME EMAIL PHONE_NUMBER HIRE_DATE JOB_ID SALARY COMMISSION_PCT MANAGER_ID DEPARTMENT_ID
    100 Steven King SKING 515.123.4567 17-JUN-03 AD_PRES 24000
```

Comment: Re *"I know that the request is not correct"*: What happens? What is the symptom?

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it:

```
USE [tempdb]

IF OBJECT_ID('hr') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE hr
CREATE TABLE hr (department_id int, hire_date datetime)
INSERT INTO hr VALUES (1,'20210101'),(2,'20211001'),(1,'20210801')

SELECT * FROM hr

SELECT department_id, AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, hire_date, getdate())) AS "days"
from hr
group by department_id

SELECT department_id, AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, hire_date, getdate())) AS "days"
from hr
group by department_id
having AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, hire_date, getdate())) > (SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY, hire_date, getdate())) AS "days" from hr)
```